# Continue MIP optimization in Gurobi / Drake

Tags: drake

If I have a long running optimization, I would like to know the quality of the best solutions it is finding.

One way I can see this working:
I do an optimization run with a time limit of 15 minutes. I can then check the result of the optimization, then somehow load the optimization (including the entire branch and bound tree, not just binaries) and do another 15 minutes, and so on. How would I do this loading / resuming of the last MIP optimization session?

Or, if there's another good way to incrementally check the solutions of long-running optimization in Gurobi / Drake, that would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Gurobi, you can add a callback function. One could imagine to use this callback function to print out the best solutions found so far, with the lower and upper bounds on the MIP cost.

You can use Drake's function [GurobiSolver::AddMipNodeCallback](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_gurobi_solver.html#a94d6956a6a9ef1ac012dcf6c582ef3cc) to add the callback.

Comment: Neither of the two Mip callbacks provide the solution data though, do they?  They only provide node counts and such.

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri I'm about to try it out, but indeed my use case is I want to export the solution data to disk whenever we find a feasible solution. From the docs for AddMipNodeCallback, it says: "Arbitrary data that will be passed to the user callback function." Not sure what arbitrary data is

Comment: I think the "arbitrary data" or "user data" in the docs is a copy-paste typo.  There is no extra data to see/use.

Comment: Yes I have investigated it. The callback takes in as input two types of data:  an object with some meta-properties e.g. best objective value, and the second object is a mathematical program. I should be able to retrieve all I need from the 2nd object!

Comment: Actually this is tricky... the MathematicalProgram is not MathematicalProgramResult. There seems to be no way to retrieve solution. Any possibility we can enable retrieving solution?

Comment: The callback provides GurobiSolverInfo in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/68c8ea9b8609b5f721f91f828e22c19af35a1e33/solvers/gurobi_solver.h#L81-L94, which contains the best solution objective. Could you use this as the progress?

Comment: I think HoliInn wants to do things like checkpoint the decision variables to disk periodically, not just monitor the progress.  I think its safe to say Drake doesn't support that yet.  It would be helpful if you could open a [feature request ticket](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/new/choose) explaining exactly what information you'd like to have available in the callback.